# Probability that the article is error free can be express as $\frac{p}{q}$

Tags: probability

> Mr. $A$ write the article . The article is originally is error free. each day Mr.$B$ introduced
>
> one new error into the article,at the end of the day Mr. A check the article and has $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3}$ chance
>
> of catching each individual error still in the article, after $3$ days probability that the article
>
> is error  free  can be express as $\displaystyle \frac{p}{q}\;,$ Where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime number, Then $(p,q),$ is

I did not understand from where i start that problem, Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: In order for the article to be error free Mr A must

- Catch the first error on the first, second, or third day. IE: not miss it thrice.
- Catch the second error on the second or third day. IE: not miss it twice.
- Catch the third error on the third day. IE: not miss it once.

Can you evaluate the probability of *not* missing an error on $k$ checks?

---

Step 2: Express that probability as a quotient of relatively prime numbers $p, q$.

Do you know what relatively prime means?  The solution follows from the definition.

Comment: Thanks Graham Kemp, although I know relatively Prime number, Would to like to explain me in detail, Thanks